# Error running PEPK tool android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, key

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the PEPK tool

C:\Users\Prashant Yadav\AndroidStudioProjects\Project1>java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=keystore --alias=key --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092771fb833b656cd48b9de6a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/wireless/android/vending/developer/signing/tools/extern/export/ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: java -version "1.7.0_79"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why @MatPag comment got deleted. Anyways, upgrading jdk to 1.8 solved the issue.

Comment: I have updated my JDK 1.7 to 1.8 and set in the variable path but getting same Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

If you are a Windows OS user, this answer can help

1. copy `pepk.jar` file in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin`
2. open command line to this directory and past your google command like this:
   `java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=my-upload-key.keystore --alias=my-key-alias --output=encrypted_private_key_path ....`
3. change your `--keystore` and `--alias` and then run command